# How to retrieve a json without the use of database?

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework

I want to scrape a website using python and send as json the information that I got to my flutter application without saving it to the database.

I don't want to use the Django Restframework database. I want to send a string to the backend and trigger a function that scrapes a certain website and sends back a json to the client. Without using the database.

Answer (score 0):

For simple usage, you can setup a view function, bind it to a url that will accept your string, and inside the function build the logic to scrape the third-party page and return a `JsonResponse`

Something like below:

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my_scrape/<str:input_string>', views.scrape)
]
```

in views.py:

```
def scrape(request, input_string):
    #scrape a website
    url = 'http://google.com/{}'.format(input_string)
    third_party_data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
    my_payload = { 'data1' : third_party_data.find(text='data1') }
    return JsonResponse(my_payload)
```

Note that this doesn't account for anything like errors and timeouts from the third-party, you will have to handle those errors in your view function, depending on what you receive.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it